# Is there a dart package to decode an ms word document and edit in a flutter application?

Tags: ms-word, dart, flutter

I am creating a flutter app which needs to import an ms word document, which already has some bookmarks for it. I need to decode the the word document and edit those bookmarks programatically.

There are packages for decoding xml and excel files like **xml: ^3.2.3** and **spreadsheet_decoder: ^1.0.0**, but I cannot find anything for decoding ms word documents.

I have done this in **VBA** using this code

```
Sub UpdateBookmark(BookmarkToUpdate As String, TextToUse As String)
Dim BMRange As range
Set wordDoc = wordDoc_c
wordDoc.ActiveWindow.View.ReadingLayout = False
With wordDoc.Application.ActiveDocument
    .Bookmarks(BookmarkToUpdate).range.Text = TextToUse
End With
End Sub
```

I expect to import the file, decode it and edit at the place of **bookmarks**. Please help me if you have a way to do this.

Answer (score -4):

I'm glad to inform you that Aspose.Words Cloud Dart SDK has become available recently: https://pub.dev/packages/aspose_words_cloud.

You may do what you want to do with the following code:

```
  // Configure words api client
  // You may get AppKey and AppSid here https://dashboard.aspose.cloud/dashboard.
  // 150 requests are available for free per month.
  var configuration = new Configuration('AppKey', 'AppSid');
  var wordsApi = new WordsApi(configuration);

  // Upload file to cloud
  var localFileContent = await (new File('fileStoredLocal.docx').readAsBytes());
  var uploadRequest = new UploadFileRequest(ByteData.view(localFileContent.buffer), 'fileStoredInCloud.docx');
  await wordsApi.uploadFile(uploadRequest);

  // Change document bookmark
  var bookmarkData = new BookmarkData()
    ..text = 'New bookmark text';
  var updateBookmarkRequest = new UpdateBookmarkRequest('fileStoredInCloud.docx', bookmarkData, 'bookmarkName');
  await wordsApi.updateBookmark(updateBookmarkRequest);

  // Download changed document from cloud
  var downloadRequest = new DownloadFileRequest('fileStoredInCloud.docx');
  var changedDocument = await wordsApi.downloadFile(downloadRequest);
  (new File('fileStoredLocal.docx')).writeAsBytes(changedDocument.buffer.asUint8List(changedDocument.offsetInBytes, changedDocument.lengthInBytes));
```

Hope it helps, otherwise please feel free to ask additional questions.

Disclaimer: I'm a product manager of Aspose.Words Cloud.